# How to make 2 inline elements with 0 margin?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I have `FlowDocument`

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="foo" />
        <Run Text="bar" />
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

How to make 'foo' and 'bar' appear with no space in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="foo" /><Run Text="bar" />
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I've noticed that if you keep the Run elements on the same line it prints it without the space.

Comment: Oh, I see, XML treats whitespaces as single space in `Content` of `Paragraph`